# return the position of the first occurrence of a value that can occur multiple times in the sorted list of values using Binary Search

Tags: python

for example if list= [2,3,3,4,5,7,7,9,10],

i want to return index 1.

**In this case,there is no target parameter unlike the usual way we do binary search**

[**Updated**]

[This is the code that I have for now.It should return 1 since the first occurence of a multiple value,which is 2,is at index 1

[Link for photo of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUzvi.png)

[**Updated**]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the index of an item in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-in-a-list)

Comment: What code have you tried, and what isn't working? Please try to research and attempt before you ask.

Comment: you can refer to my updated description for more details about my problem

Answer (score 0):

Perform your binary search as usual; but when you arrive at the item you searched for, keep searching to the left.

I.e.:

- Set `min` to the first index, `max` to the last (plus one).
- Look at the one in the middle (`(min+max)/2`).
- If the value there is larger than the one you are searching for, set `max` to that index; else that `min` to it (plus one).
- Repeat until you find an index with the value you are looking for.
- So far this was just the regular binary search. Now store that index; it is your current best candidate. Act like the value you found was larger than what you were looking for (i.e., set `max` to that index), and continue with the search.

When you run out of search space (i.e., `min` = `max`), the last "candidate" you found is the lowest index of the value you searched for.

Comment: in regards to your third point,i do not have a preset value at the start to search for.My function must not require that and yet be able to find the first occurence of a multiple value and return its index.

Comment: @LowWijjy: I see; I'd suggest to add that more explicitly to the question to increase the chance for someone to come up with a good idea. As you see, both my algorith and bhaskar's implementation of it do not really "understand" it correctly...

Answer (score -1):

i am sharing you code snippet which will help to find your answer

```
int leftIndex(int arr[], int n, int x)
{
    int l = 0, h = n-1;
    int mid = 0;

    while(l <= h)
    {
        mid = l + (h-l)/2;

        if(arr[mid] == x && (mid == 0 || arr[mid-1] != x))
          return mid;

        else if(arr[mid] >= x)
          h = mid-1;
        else l = mid + 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

You just need to understand this code . 
this is as simple as binary search code. just a single condition where we need to modify the so that we can get required result

Comment: your x variable in this case is the target parameter that i dont require in my example of binary search.My binary search function would not have a target parameter to search of,no preset value to be found

Comment: Hi there .. we  use binary search to find respective value .  we can't use binary search f we don't know what to find .  but i worked on your problem to find the required anwer in O(1) time complexity ..  int arr[]={2,3,6,9,11,12,12,19,20};
  int n=9;
  unordered_set<int> us;
  
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
      if(us.find(arr[i])!=us.end())
        {
            cout<<i-1<<endl;
            break;
        }
        else
        us.insert(arr[i]);
  } result should be 5 as 12 is  appearing at index 5 considering 0 based indexing